# Almost sure convergence for expected value of indicator function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $Z$ a random variable which is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a class of events, closed under intersection which generates the $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{G}$ (i.e $\mathscr{G}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$) and $\mathbb{E}[{Z \mathbf{1}_B}]=\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$ for every $B \in \mathcal{C} $

and  $\mathbb{E}[{Z \mathbf{1}_B}]=0$ for every $B \in \mathcal{G}$ then how show that :
$Z = 0 $ almost sure.

**Proposal**

If $Z\geq 0$, then we may argue that
$$
\mathscr{G}\ni \mathcal{C}\mapsto \mathbb{E}[Z \mathbf{1}_{B}] 
$$
are measures that agree on the $\pi$-system $\mathscr{G}$ and thus also on the sigma-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathscr{G}$.

Now for a general $Z\in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ we have
$$
\mathscr{G}\ni \mathcal{C} \mapsto \mathrm{E}[Z^{+}|B]+\mathrm{E}[Z^-| B]
$$

are measures that agree on the $\pi-\lambda$-system.

Comment: Easy application of $\pi -\lambda $ theorem.

Comment: Can you please explain it an answer?I will appreciate it

Comment: If you have heard of this theorem then you should make attempt to answer the question. If you get stuck you can get help. But not attempting to answer it yourself may lead to downvotes and close votes.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#The_%CF%80-%CE%BB_theorem for a statement. A similar question is also asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945675/prove-that-if-expectations-agree-on-a-pi-system-then-they-agree-on-the-sigma-al which you can try to use

Comment: I will try it .$\pi - \lambda$ theorem for a.s?

Comment: I read it and edited my question in the proposal but I am stuck

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I was thinking another way professor.That is if $Z \in \mathscr{G}$ and $\mathbb{E}|Z|< \infty$ then : 
$$\mathbb{E}[Z \cdot \mathbf{1}_{B} |\mathscr{G} ] =\mathbf{1}_{B} \cdot \mathbb{E}[Z  |\mathscr{G} ].  $$

Because $\mathscr{G}$ is a $\pi-\lambda$-system that means that $Z$ is independent.So $\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathscr{G}] = \mathbb{E}[Z]=0$

Comment: Your proposal works fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but how this shows that $Z=0$ a.s?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $Z$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable an $EZ1_B=0$ for all $B \in \mathcal G$ we have $EZ1_{Z>0}=0$ and $EZ1_{Z<0}=0$. But this implies that $P(Z>0)=0$ and $P(Z<0)=0$ so $Z=0$ almost surely.

Comment: alright but why almost sure ?

Comment: $Z=0$a.s. means $P(Z\neq 0)=0$.

Comment: THANK YOU PROFESSOR !!!!!!